# Get the first number in a string in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script returns a value like `33 | 4` and I need only the the first whole number, in this case `33`.

Can I use `.replace( /[^\d].*/, '' )` and where/how to put this? Or is there better solutions?

You are all very helpful, but i'm in a stage where I need to see my full script or a line from it with you solutions implemented ;-)

Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input_1_1").blur(function() {
    // sets the value of #input_1_8 to
    // that which was entered in #input_1_1
    $("#input_1_8").val($("#input_1_1").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Just call `parseInt()` on the value. It will read all leading digits until a non-digit character is found: https://jsfiddle.net/c27xfdoh/

Comment: `str.split(/\D+/)[0]`

Comment: use `"33 | 4".split('|').map(a=> trim(a))[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseInt()` or split your string with `|` and get the first result

```js
console.log(parseInt("33 | 4"))
// or
console.log("33 | 4".split(" | ")[0])
```

In your case you can do

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input_1_1").blur(function() {
    $("#input_1_8").val(parseInt($("#input_1_1").val()));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var str = "33 | 4";
var res = str.split("|");//split with '|' it will return array
console.log(res[0].trim());//33
```

You can do trim on it or parseInt, whatever you want to get your task done.

Answer (score -1):

With split you can split a string with any character, my example:

```
<script>

var stringexample="45.89 | 65";
alert(takefirst(sting));
}

function takefirst(){
var a=string.split("|");
return a[0]
}
</script>
```

Also you can use split for separete character for character like this

```
var a=stringexample.split("");
for(var i=0;i<a.lenght;i++){
alert(a[i]);
}
```

Alerts:

```
4
5
.
8
```

Etc..

Comment: Firstly, please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them. Secondly this will return `3`, not `33`

Comment: Chill, i not was finished my answer and you post a comment let me one minute be chill be happy

Comment: I am very happy :) My point, which you seem to be missing, is that your answer does not return what the OP is asking for.

Comment: My bad so, sorry

Comment: No problem. If you edit the answer to correct it I'll gladly remove my downvote

Comment: You think is a correct answer now?